# Re use data in a model in multiple view MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a user model for a C# web app that I populate in a controller with various properties like username etc.

I'd just like to know if there is a place where I can instantiate this class once and then reuse it in multiple controllers as currently I have it setup so that every single controller creates a new instance of User adds the relevant data to it and passes it to it's view but this doesn't seem efficient!

Comment: Create a `BaseController` and put you common stuff in its constructor and have all you controllers inherit from `BaseController`

Comment: I do like this idea too but perhaps for more area specific things and not across the whole app itself so thanks!

Comment: You have accepted an answer for using `MemoryCache` which is fine for certain global data that wont ever change but its not suitable for storing user data - for that you need session

Comment: You are correct I do indeed!

Comment: Suggest you add it to Session in the login method. And in a `BaseController` you could have a (say) UserData property which gets the object from Session (or if it does not exist, gets it from the database)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, if you put it in an answer I'd be more than happy to tick, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a small amount of data consider using a custom `IPrincipal` (or `Claims` if your using `Identity`) so its avaliable in the FormsAuthenticationTicket. Otherwise you can store the data in `Session` to avoid repeated database calls.

In addition, consider a `BaseController` class (from which all your controllers inherit) which contains a property or method to read the object from Session (and gets the object from the database in case `Session` has expired or has been  recycled)

Answer (score 1):

you can cache your data using `MemoryCache` :

```
public class InMemoryCache: ICacheService
{
    public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        T item = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
        }
        return item;
    }
}

interface ICacheService
{
    T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class;
}
```

Usage: `var user=cacheService.GetOrSet("User", ()=>Repository.GetUser())`

Or implement CacheRepository pattern ( [CacheRepo pattern description](http://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern) )